# using stored procedure find cause of dis-ordering of the result set

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

i m facing a problem in sql stored procedure. i have a stored procedure which contains a dynamic sql query, creation of temp tables,  inserting datas into this temp tables. in my local the result of this stored procedure displays fine. but in Production environment the ordering of result is changed. i have only the select permission for that production, so i am not able to run that sp in Production database. can any one suggests any solution. is there any possibility to run that SP and view the result in production sp. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your question isn't very specific, but if you are relying on the order of results and you're not using an `ORDER BY` on the query that returns the results (in your case, it's likely the last statement) then you should.  The order of results is not guaranteed unless you use `ORDER BY`.

If you already are, perhaps you could post the relevant parts of your query.

Comment: thanks for all your responses. order by is done in query. the main issue is that it is happening for only one stored procedure not to other Sp's. please let me know in case u need any other details

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the Collation of the two databases is the same. Assuming MS Sql Server, right-click the database node in Mgmt Studio and view Properties. The collation will be something like `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

If they don't match, it's possible that the 'natural' sort order will be different unless you specify an explicit `ORDER BY`clause.

Comment: hi in both the environment collation is same. here is the brief description of query.   first we are selecting the records and inserting into the temp table. then created one more temp table to store the final results. in this temp table first we are inserting the headings.'insert into #TempChaseReport values(''Student FName'',''Student LName'',''Practice Exam 1'',''Practice Exam 2'')'

Comment: then i am looping thru the selected records in the first step and inserting it in the this tempChaseReport table. after inserting all records, i created one more temp table, where i m doing the following query. insert into #TempChaseReport2 Select * FROM #TempChaseReport where id_num=1                         
 insert into #TempChaseReport2 Select * FROM #TempChaseReport                        
  where id_num!=1  order by MgrLoginID,LastName,myflag  i m doing order by.

Comment: at the end when i m finally selecting the records to display.

Comment: I see you're doing a `SELECT *` but the `ORDER BY` lists specific columns. Have you tried seeing what happens when you order by EVERY colum explicitly? Then, remove them from the `ORDER BY` clause 1 by 1 until the sort oders differ - at that point, you know what the problem column is.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possibilities off the top of my head without more info :

1) The production and your local environment are configured differently, especially with regard to the collation of the tempdb database (which will be the default collation used by temporary tables unless you specify otherwise in their CREATE statement). Therefore any ordering of character fields will behave differently.

2) You're not doing any specific ordering at all, in which case the 'default' order is dictated by many things and is unlikely to be the same between servers.

Comment: i have done order by in stored procedure. i am just checking the collation in both the database. thanks for your reply.

Comment: collation are same in both the database. please let me know if any other parameter is there.